# iPhone Gigya integration sharing Facebook, twitter inconsistency

Tags: facebook, twitter, authentication, ios4, gigya

I am  currently integrating facebook and twitter for iphone with gigya.

For Twitter sometimes its sharing and sometimes don't. Facebook also happening same as well.

lately facebook not even opening its login in screen. On device unlike simulator delegate methods like LoginDidFail, DidLogin called more than once.not sure why.

I am not storing any object to store provider info when login happens.

Can you please let me know why this inconsis

Comment: can you please share  some codes. I am also trying to integrate it.I am getting the response "Request has expired"

Comment: Hi Krishna, I found gigya not working from the past two days in my iphone.Did you face any problem in using gigya in iphone?Does it works properly now?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a multi part question.I would need more information to get a clearer understanding. Please provide code snippets if possible. Meanwhile, please see see my responses below:

1. Inconsistent Sharing

   - This might be something to do with how your userAction is being defined.
     (http://wiki.gigya.com/030_API_reference/010_Client_API/010_Objects/UserAction_object)
2. Login Screen not loading

   - Typically this is down to social Network Applications not set up correctly.
     (http://wiki.gigya.com/035_Socialize_Setup/005_Opening_External_Applications)
3. Event Delegate methods called repeatedly

   - This may be down do multiple instances of the GSAPI class.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code snippet

GSAPI *gsAPI // declared this in header file

gsAPI = [[GSAPI alloc] initWithAPIKey:XX viewController:self]; // i kept this in viewDidload

// add this code to have facebook and twitter on provider list. this was put in in one method which will be called when user tries to share

GSDictionary *pParams5 = [[GSDictionary new] autorelease]; [pParams5 putStringValue:@"facebook,twitter" forKey:@"enabledProviders"];
[gsAPI showAddConnectionsUI:pParams5 delegate:self context:nil];

//this method called when login fails -(void)gsLoginUIDidFail:(int)errorCode errorMessage:(NSString*)errorMessage context:(id)context {

}

// this method called on successful login 
- (void) gsLoginUIDidLogin:(NSString*)provider user:(GSDictionary*)user context:(id)context {

GSDictionary *userAction = [[GSDictionary new] autorelease];

[userAction putStringValue:@"title" forKey:@"title"];

[userAction putStringValue:@"userMessage" forKey:@"userMessage"];

[userAction putStringValue:@"desc" forKey:@"description"];

[userAction putStringValue:@"imageurl" forKey:@"linkBack"];

GSDictionary *pParams5 = [[GSDictionary new] autorelease];

[pParams5 putGSDictionaryValue:userAction forKey:@"userAction"];

[gsAPI sendRequest:@"socialize.publishUserAction" params:pParams5 delegate:self context:nil];

}

-(void) gsDidReceiveResponse:(NSString*)method response:(GSResponse*)response context:(id)context  {
//showing alert messages on successful sharing
//this method getting called more than twice on device
}